# Search string and integer table javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I encountered a problem again when I search for something it returns the first row table that is sorted when I type random letter and number it only displays the first row of the table. What seems to be wrong in this I added a sort on the heading. How can I correct this?

HTML

```
     <table id="mytable">
           <thead>
             <tr>
             <th id="date_distribution">Date of Distribution</th>
             <th id="semi_total" class = 'text-center'>Semi Total</th>
             <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
                </thead>
            <tr>
            <th>November 30 2017</th>
            <th>₱20,175.10</th>
            </tr>
             <tr>
            <th>December 15 2017</th>
            <th>₱19,838.20</th>
            </tr>
    </table>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```

This is the code for the sort and the search

```
function sortTable(f,n){
    var rows = $('#mytable tbody  tr').get();

    rows.sort(function(a, b) {

        var A = getVal(a);
        var B = getVal(b);

        if(A < B) {
            return -1*f;
        }
        if(A > B) {
            return 1*f;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    function getVal(elm){
        var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
        if($.isNumeric(v)){
            v = parseInt(v,10);
        }
        return v;
    }

    $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
        $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
    });
}
var f_date_distribution = 1;
var f_semi_total = 1;
$("#date_distribution").click(function(){
    f_date_distribution *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_date_distribution,n);
});
$("#semi_total").click(function(){
    f_semi_total *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_semi_total,n);
});

$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $('#mytable tbody  tr').each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.find("td:first").text();
            var id2 = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0 && id2.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input isn't expected(means you might type a capital letter or not), you should check the letter by using `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()`

```js
$("#search").on("keyup", function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    
    $('#mytable tbody  tr').each(function(index) {
  $row = $(this);
  
  var id = $row.find("th:first-child").text();
  var id2 = $row.find("th:last-child").text();
  if(id.toUpperCase().indexOf(value.toUpperCase()) > -1 || id.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1 || 
      id2.indexOf(value) > -1){
      $row.show(); 
  }
  else {
   $row.hide();
   return;
  }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
       <thead>
         <tr>
         <th id="date_distribution">Date of Distribution</th>
         <th id="semi_total" class = 'text-center'>Semi Total</th>
         <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
            </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>November 30 2017</th>
        <th>₱20,175.10</th>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>December 15 2017</th>
        <th>₱19,838.20</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```

Comment: my bad supposed to be td not th

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have another question how can you search for the string of month it displays only on the first letter when you type the remaining it returns a blank and for the amount without the need for the comma

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: when you type no for november it doesnt show november it display a blank

Comment: @John Sorry, I've fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `tbody` and `td` in your HTML. Also, loop through `#mytable tr` instead of `#mytable tbody tr`. Please check the updated code below.

```js
function sortTable(f,n){
    var rows = $('#mytable tbody  tr').get();

    rows.sort(function(a, b) {

        var A = getVal(a);
        var B = getVal(b);

        if(A < B) {
            return -1*f;
        }
        if(A > B) {
            return 1*f;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    function getVal(elm){
        var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
        if($.isNumeric(v)){
            v = parseInt(v,10);
        }
        return v;
    }

    $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
        $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
    });
}
var f_date_distribution = 1;
var f_semi_total = 1;
$("#date_distribution").click(function(){
    f_date_distribution *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_date_distribution,n);
});
$("#semi_total").click(function(){
    f_semi_total *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_semi_total,n);
});

$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $('#mytable tr').each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.find("td:first").text();
            var id2 = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0 && id2.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
           <thead>
             <tr>
             <th id="date_distribution">Date of Distribution</th>
             <th id="semi_total" class = 'text-center'>Semi Total</th>
             <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>November 30 2017</td>
            <td>₱20,175.10</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
            <td>December 15 2017</td>
            <td>₱19,838.20</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```

Comment: The result isn't coming out. Did you even check your code?

Comment: @moon Yes I checked and it works properly. Feel free to run and check

Comment: Maybe it's because of JSfiddle? Because it's not running properly :(

Comment: @moon There is no jsfiddle. Click on the 'Run code snippet' button and enter just 'D' and the second row will be shown which is December. Then try with the second column. make sure you copy paste the '₱' symbol.

Comment: Live search usually should support a user to search for something regardless of capital/lower letters.

Comment: @moon agree with you. But that was not a requirement in the question here. Purpose of the answer was to correcting the existing error.

Comment: Do you really think it's not included in `"requirement"`? Do you think people think 'it is working 100%' if they have to distinguish a capital / lower letter every time they input something..? The title 'Live Search' generally includes everything that it's supposed to need. I agree with you in some way, because we don't have to make an extra function, but this, stackoverflow, doesn't really have to be a business :( It's helping-communicating community